# Salesforce Field updates

Tags: administration

To avoid duplicates we have customized Email thing..I have to two Fields,Primary Email & Secondary Email so if Primary Email is blank than Secondary email value be updated in Primary Email field & secondary email value should be cleared.
Note-Secondary Email field type is Text.

How to clear the secondary Email field after updation.Can anybody guide on this..???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume email as primary email

```
trigger SalesCommunity on Contact (before insert, before update) {

    for(Contact cot: trigger.new) {
        if(cot.Email == null && cot.Secondary_Email__c != null){
            cot.Email = cot.Secondary_Email__c;
            cot.Secondary_Email__c = null;            
        }
    }
}
```